# Why when i clone/duplicate gameobject the memory usage is getting to 98%?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void CreateCubesBesideWaypoints()
    {
        const int lightCount = 20;
        Vector3[] lightPositions = new Vector3[lightCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            posToChunkDistances(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[waypoints.Length - 1].transform.position, lightPositions, lightCount);
            for (int x = 0; x < lightPositions.Length; x++)
            {
                lightPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                GameObject cloneLightPrefab = Instantiate(lightPrefab, lightPositions[x], Quaternion.identity);
                cloneLightPrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
                cloneLightPrefab.tag = "LightPrefab";
                //cloneLightPrefab.transform.SetParent(lightPrefab.transform);
            }
        }
    }
```

This way it's working fine. But if i'm using the line:

```
cloneLightPrefab.transform.SetParent(lightPrefab.transform);
```

Then the memory usage is getting to 98% and i need to restart the pc.
The lightPrefab is a Cube GameObject i drag to this script.
And what i want to do is to put all the new cloneLightPrefab gameobjects under the lightPrefab as children.

And a sub question, In the inner loop on the line:

```
for (int x = 0; x < lightPositions.Length; x++)
```

Should i change it to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < lightPositions.Length - 1; x++)
```

Comment: lightPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red; call to many times... You can move it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There so many problems in your code so this answer will be long.

**1**.First of all, you don't need the outer loop: `for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)`. Please remove that. That was not included in my last answer and I can't tell why you added it there. This will increase how much time you spend in the loop.

**2**.You are modifying a prefab when you did `lightPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;` You should be modifying the cloned object instead. `cloneLightPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;`

**3**.Don't set the parent of the instantiated object to be a prefab. That's what you are doing with `cloneLightPrefab.transform.SetParent(lightPrefab.transform);`.

Create an empty GameObject then use it as a parent for all light objects you instantiate.  `GameObject parentObject = new GameObject("LightParentObj");` then `cloneLightPrefab.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);`.

Please look a [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/prefabs-concept-usage) post for how to create prefabs if you don't know that already.

Your fixed code should look something more like this:

```
void CreateCubesBesideWaypoints()
{
    const int lightCount = 20;
    Vector3[] lightPositions = new Vector3[lightCount];

    posToChunkDistances(waypoints[0].transform.position, waypoints[waypoints.Length - 1].transform.position, lightPositions, lightCount);
    GameObject parentObject = new GameObject("LightParentObj");
    for (int x = 0; x < lightPositions.Length; x++)
    {
        GameObject cloneLightPrefab = Instantiate(lightPrefab, lightPositions[x], Quaternion.identity);
        cloneLightPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        cloneLightPrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        cloneLightPrefab.tag = "LightPrefab";
        cloneLightPrefab.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);
    }
}
```

> Should i change it to: for (int x = 0; x < lightPositions.Length - 1;
>   x++)

**No**.

When you have `for (int x = 0; x < lightPositions.Length; x++)`,
the loop starts from `0` and ends with `lightPositions.Length - 1`.

If you change it to `for (int x = 0; x < lightPositions.Length - 1; x++)`, the loop will start from `0` and end with `lightPositions.Length - 2`. Basically, the loop would not finish looping over all the items in the array.

I do think you should Google and understand `for` loop with array in C# before you continue coding. It's one of those basic stuff you **must** know.

**Note**:

One of the times it may be fine to use `for (int x = 0; x < lightPositions.Length - 1; x++)` is when you use `<=` instead of `<`.

For example, `for (int x = 0; x <= lightPositions.Length - 1; x++)`. In this case, the loop will still loop over all the items in the array.

Comment: The reason i did the outer loop is because if i will do: posToChunkDistances(waypoints[0].transform.position, waypoints[waypoints.Length - 1].transform.position, lightPositions, lightCount); it will put cubes only on one waypoint. But in waypoints i have more then one waypoints. That's why i added before the for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++). I want to create cubes beside each waypoint route in waypoints.

Comment: Not really. Way point starts from `0` index and ends at `waypoints.Length - 1`. The `posToChunkDistances` function takes two positions: 1.The beginning of the postion which is `waypoints[0].transform.position`. 2.The end of the position which is `waypoints.Length - 1`. If you pass it in those two positions, it will generate points between those two positions. The distance of those points will be equal and that's what you want.

Comment: It will store the generated evenly points in the `lightPositions` array variable. That we loop over and instantiate the light over each of those positions. The main reason I am not erectly looping over the `waypoints` is because we are not sure that the lines are evenly created. We also don't have control of how many points should be generated.

Comment: With the `posToChunkDistances` function, we can generate any amount of points/lights that are 100% equally apart from one another just by using the first index from the waypoint and the last index from the waypoint.

Comment: If you don't care about how many light should be generated or you don't care about the distance between each one being equal, then simply remove the `posToChunkDistances` function and just loop over your `waypoint`. That should do it. Right now, you are generating 20 lights but can change it because of that `posToChunkDistances` function. You can't by just using the `waypoints`.